# Rails DateTime field has current date/time if nil in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a form with a `datetime` field. Since Rails 3.2.13 doesn't support `type="datetime-local"` `input` fields yet (and I'm not ready to move to 4.0 beta), I'm doing this manually:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="person[my_date_time]"<% if @person.my_date_time %> value="<%=@person.my_date_time.strftime('%FT%T')%>"<% end %>/>
```

The problem is @person.my_date_time will be the current date/time if it's `nil` in the database. And it outputs with seconds too which screws up Chrome's handling of datetimes. I want that field to be empty if it's `nil` in the database. How can I tell? Rails' `datetime_select` method handles it the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datetime field is `nil` in the database something in your application must be changing or overwriting that value. Perhaps you have a default somewhere? It's not really possible to say what is going on without seeing more code than what is posted now. Can you post the code for you `Person` model and any other relevant code (any gems which might affect things, etc.)?

```
strftime("%FT%R")  # Will output without seconds, e.g. "2013-04-18T21:43"
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: I don't see immediately what could be initializing the `DateTime` to the current time, but that `strftime` `%R` solves the other issue of causing Chrome to do screwy things with the field, thanks!